# How can I convert DocX including CorelDraw items to PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, coreldraw

I'm trying to convert DocX files to PDF files but some of DocX files contain specific drawings. This drawings were import from CorelDraw to Doc file 10-15 years ago then convert into DocX.
The problem is that when i'm trying to "Save As PDF", all the features of the drawing are magnified...

For your information, this conversion was make on C# but, with Microsoft Word, that's fail too.

I had try to install CorelDraw but I think, link is delete.

```cs
Application appWord = new Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(path);
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdf_path, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

I hope someone know how to make this conversion with "unknow objects" without modified them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not clear from the problem description if you've tried this in the Word application interface, as a user... If you have not, then please do so. If the results are not satisfactory I recommend asking in an end-user venue whether anyone has an idea how to properly "convert" the CorelDraw objects. End-user specialists usually have more in-depth knowledge in these kinds of areas (how Word works). Something the UI can't do also can't be achieved via the object model, which simply works with what Word provides.

Comment: Another angle of investigation would be to look at the Word Open XML in order to see how these objects are being managed/saved by Word. That may give some clues as how to procede / perhaps convert them before-the-fact.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your aswer. I wanted to try to use Open XML for see how this object is build but one method works more : use "print to pdf" not "save as".
When I found the solution code for use Print PDF in C#, i'll post it here.